# Neural network input mistmatch (Iris Dataset)

Tags: matlab, neural-network, cell

I currently have an error that i can't pass this is the short code and everything needed in order to have a general idea about my problem

```
clear;

close all; clear ;
load fisheriris;

m = meas;
d = num2cell(m);


d(:,5) = species(:,1);
c = cvpartition(d(:,5),'kfold',10);
CeDam = cell(10,1);
CeVrem = cell(10,1);

for i=1:10
   CeDam{i} =  [d(test(c,i),1) d(test(c,i),2) d(test(c,i),3)  d(test(c,i),4)]';
end
for i=1:10

    CeVrem{i} =  d(test(c,i),5)';
end

for i = 1:10
    a = CeVrem{i};
    [n,m] = size(a);
    for j = 1:n
        for k = 1:m
            if isequal(a(j,k),'setosa') a{n,m} = [1 0 0];
            elseif isequal(a(j,k),'versicolor') a{n,m} = [0 1 0];
            else a{j,k} = [0,0,1];
            end
        end
    end
    CeVrem{i} = a;
end

net = newff(cell2mat(minmax(CeDam{1})),[3 3 3],{'logsig','logsig','logsig',},'trainlm');
net.LW{2,1} = net.LW{2,1}*0.5;
net.b{2} = net.b{2}*2;
net.performFcn = 'mse';
net.trainParam.epochs = 100; 

err = 0;
i = 1;
j = 1;

while i <= 10
    while j <= 10
        if i~=j net = train(net,CeDam{j},CeVrem{j});
        end
    j=j+1;
    end
end
```

in the train part of the algorithm it gives me an input mistmatch which is very odd for me.

The error messages:

> Error using trainlm (line 109) Number of inputs does not match
>   net.numInputs.
>
> Error in network/train (line 106) [net,tr] =
>   feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);

i managed to fix everything after much work here is the code that works for anyone having the same problem in the future gl :D :).

```
clear;

close all; clear ;
load fisheriris;

m = meas;
d = num2cell(m);


d(:,5) = species(:,1);
c = cvpartition(d(:,5),'kfold',10);
CeDam = cell(10,1);
CeVrem = cell(10,1);

for i=1:10
   CeDam{i} =  [m(test(c,i),1) m(test(c,i),2) m(test(c,i),3)  m(test(c,i),4)]';
end
for i=1:10

    CeVrem{i} =  d(test(c,i),5);
end

for i = 1:10
    a = CeVrem{i}';
    [n,m] = size(a);
    b = zeros(3,m);
    for j = 1:n
        for k = 1:m
            if isequal(a(j,k),{'setosa'}) b(1,k) = 1; b(2,k) = 0; b(3,k) = 0;
            elseif isequal(a(j,k),{'versicolor'}) b(1,k) = 0; b(2,k) = 1; b(3,k) = 0;
            else b(1,k) = 0; b(2,k) = 0; b(3,k) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
    CC{i} = b;
end
CC = CC';


net = newff(minmax(CeDam{1}),[3 3 3],{'logsig','logsig','logsig'},'trainlm');
net.LW{2,1} = net.LW{2,1}*0.6;
net.b{2} = net.b{2}*2;
net.performFcn = 'mse';
net.trainParam.epochs = 100; 

errglob = 0;
i = 1;
j = 1;

while i <= 10

    while j <= 10
        if i~=j net = train(net,CeDam{j},CC{j});
        end
    j=j+1;
    end
    y=sim(net,CeDam{i});
    y=round(y);
    e = y - CC{i};
    errcur=mse(net,CC{i},y);
    errglob = errglob + mse(net,CC{i},y);
    fprintf('Avem o eroare de %.2f pe foldul %d \n',errcur,i)
  i=i+1;  
end
errglob/10
```

this thread can be closed thx :)

Comment: Error using trainlm (line 109)
Number of inputs does not match net.numInputs.

Error in network/train (line 106)
[net,tr] = feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);

Comment: here you go :Dthan you for taking the time to look at my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you got some problems with mixing up cell and array formats...

Try to replace:

```
net = train(net,CeDam{j},CeVrem{j});
```

by:

```
net = train(net,cell2mat(CeDam{j}),cell2mat(CeVrem{j}')');
```

AND: please remove your infinite loops in `i`, by adding `i=i+1;` or replace the `while` loops by more natural `for` loops, e.g.

```
for i = 1:10
    for j = 1:10
        if i~=j
            net = train(net,cell2mat(CeDam{j}),cell2mat(CeVrem{j}')');
        end
    end
end
```

AND: Where are you using your `i` inside the loop? I guess something is missing there...

Comment: i know about the infinite loop it's not finished thank you let me try what you just said:d

Comment: Please note my edit - you are not (seriously) using the `i` inside the loop.

Comment: i can't use that because in "CeVrem" i have the representation of the 3 classes i have [1 0 0], [0 1 0] . [0 0 1] . If i do cell2mat on CeVrem it will ruin it it will be something like 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 or something like that :D and even if i don't do that this is the error i get Error using trainlm (line 109)
Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples.

Error in network/train (line 106)
[net,tr] = feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);

Comment: it is very odd considering one is 4x15 and the other 1x15 :D

Comment: and yes a part of the code is missing since it's irrelevant i wanted to simplify :)) y=sim(net,cellFold{i});

    e = y - cellTargets{i};
    %error = numel(find(e~=0))/length(y)
    
    err=mse(net,cellTargets{i},y);
    fprintf('Eroare pe foldul %d este %.2f \n',i,err)
    fprintf('Numarul de exemple gresite pe foldul %d este %d \\ 30 \n',i,numel(find(e~=0)))
    error = error + mse(net,cellTargets{i},y);
    i=i+1;
end this is where i is used:D i did another project but there i had only 2 classes, with 3 don't know how to code them without cells so i can use cvpartition

Comment: "it is very odd"... I didn't consider anything! Sorry for not investing hours of thinking into your problem. It was just a hint, what is going on there. And still, your while loops are bad style...